# How to prevent row click function on specific column in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am dealing with a javascript datatable with clickable rows. Each row have onclick function, but in my one column i have different links that open jquery dialogues box, on this column i want to disable row click method, how to do this ?
here is function that i implement of row click

```
$(rec' tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to disable row click for that particular column

```
$('rec' tbody'').on('click', 'td', function () {

         if ($(this).index() == 4 ) { // provide index of your column in which you prevent row click here is column of 4 index
             return;
         }

            // you can do additional functionality by clicking on this column here                         
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either check to see if what was clicked was an anchor

```
$(rec' tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (evt) {
    if ( $(evt.target).is("a") ) {
        return;
    }
    /* do whatever here */
});
```

or other option is to stop the propagation of the event from the link/cell.

Comment: This is the best answer, just use standard js/jquery functionality. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use a class or something to identify the row/column that you don't want to be clicked and check if the click event comes from this element and use `event.preventDefault()`
 to cancel action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the class for each column that you want to be clickable to something specific and the non-clickable to something else.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="clickable">click this</td>
    <td class="clickable">and this</td>
    <td class="something-else">but not this</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then have your jQuery just do something on the class rather than the `<tr>`

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works but there may be people looking to interact with the row and not the column clicked. For those cases try this:

```
table.on("click", 'tbody tr td', function() {
    if ($(this).index() == 10) return false;
    var $row = $(this).parent()  // this is the row you wanted
    var theRow =   table.row($row);
    //var artcode = theRow.data()[4];
    // Further logic goes here
});
```